# Implementing CompletableFuture recursively

Tags: java, recursion, iteration, scheduled-tasks, completable-future

I have three Tasks:

`createSimulationScenarios()`, `runSimulation()`, and `getSimulationOutput()`

These tasks are done in an iterative manner:

1. `createSimulationScenarios()` creates new simulation files
2. `runSimulation()` runs a simulation. If there are many simulations they can be executed in parallel batches.
3. `getSimulationOutput()` crunches the output data as soon as a simulation is done. Can also be done in parallel as long as the specific simulation is already finished.

Then when all simulations are finished and all outputs are obtained, `createSimulationScenarios()` creates a new set of simulation files based on the previous batch's output. And so on...

Because *each* `runSimulation()` and *each* `getSimulationOutput()` can be done in parallel, I thought of using `CompletableFuture` for the implementation.

```
for (i = 0; i < noSimulations; ++i) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> runSim = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new runSimulation(), simulationExecutor);
    CompletableFuture<Void> getOutput = runSim.thenCompose(x ->
                                        CompletableFuture.runAsync(new getSimulationOutput(), outputExecutor));
}
```

However, I am stuck on how to connect this chunk to another `CompletableFuture` for  `createSimulationScenarios()` with the requirement that it only starts to execute when all simulations and outputs have finished (which is the start of the next iteration).

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want to wait for all stages to complete then maybe [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) can help

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ForkJoinTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html), it seems to fit perfectly for the computation-heavy tasks which scale to run optimally in different environments

[RecursiveTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html) reference shows the example of a simple implementation

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using recursion, you can stick with iteration, but it seems an infinite loop is what you're looking for. This example uses an infinite stream. The `CompletableFuture` calls will probably need to be changed according to the exact behavior desired (translation: I doubt it will compile, just showing what the code could look like).

```
Stream.generate(() -> createSimulationScenarios())
    .map(simulations -> IntStream.range(0, simulations.size())
       .mapToObj(i -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(new runSimulation(), simulationExecutor)
          .thenCompose(x -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(new getSimulationOutput(), 
                            outputExecutor)))
       .collect(Collectors.toList())) // force tasks to be submitted
    .forEach(futureList -> futureList.stream().forEach(CompletableFuture::join));
```